# Azure data factory how to use expression builder to create DDL statement. Using script activity In ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

this is the script 1 activity below json output.

```
 {
    "resultSetCount": 1,
    "recordsAffected": 78,
    "resultSets": [
        {
            "rowCount": 78,
            "rows": [
                {
                    "name": "employee",
                    "type": "NUMBER(12,0)",
                    "kind": "COLUMN",
                    "null?": "Y",
                    "default": null,
                    "primary key": "N",
                    "unique key": "N",
                    "check": null,
                    "expression": null,
                    "comment": "",
                    "policy name": null,
                    "privacy domain": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "salary",
                    "type": "VARCHAR(16777216)",
                    "kind": "COLUMN",
                    "null?": "Y",
                    "default": null,
                    "primary key": "N",
                    "unique key": "N",
                    "check": null,
                    "expression": null,
                    "comment": "",
                    "policy name": null,
                    "privacy domain": null
```

I want create sql table script based on the name and type. from the adove script 1 json output.

Example:- Create table emp(

employee NUMBER(12,0),
salary VARCHAR(16777216)
....
);

Answer (score 0):

> I want create sql table script based on the name and type. from the adove script 1 json output.

To achieve this follow below steps:

1. Take Foreach activity and pass the output of script activity to foreach activity with expression like below.

```json
@activity('script').output.resultSets[0].rows
```

[image]
2. Take append variable activity under for each and use below expression to create appropriate array of column names and type

```json
@concat(item().name,' ',item().type)
```

[image]

3. After this take set variable activity to create query using dynamic expression as below

```json
@concat('create table emp (', join(variables('sample'),','),')')
```

[image]

**Output:**'

[image]